# Вложенные документы Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Привет, только начинаю работать с MongoDB и NodeJS

Необходимо сделать вложенную структуру категорий, вида:

Category = title, desc, subcategories: []

Как правильно описать схему?

Answer (score 3):

```
var schema = new Schema({
title : String, 
desc  : String, 
subcategories: []
});

var Category = mongoose.model('Category', schema);
```

// subcategories: [] (могут быть варианты: [String] либо [Number] либо просто пустой массив)

Задавайте вопросы, если что-то непонятно будет.